# How does this equation simplify to another?

Tags: logarithms, fractions

How does $(2x+3)/4 - \ln(2x+3)/4$ simplify to $(-\ln(2x+3)-2x)/4$?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

You can simply equate what you have on left to right... you will end up with
$2x+3=-2x$, which is not true.